# Arbitrary \n introduced during during AppsScript when sending an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

First, all of the code below works fine, there is no issues in terms of functionality .

```
  function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Active");
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6); // Retrieve first six columns, including the timestamp column
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var folderId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByName('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf');

  if (!files.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log('File not found.');
    return;
  }

  var file = files.next();
  var message = sheet.getRange("H2").getValue(); // Retrieve message from cell H2

  var sentEmails = {}; // Object to track emails that have been sent

  // Group emails by domain
  var emailsByDomain = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[4]; // Email address from Column E
    var timestamp = row[5]; // Timestamp from Column F

    // Skip if timestamp exists or email address is invalid
    if (timestamp || !emailAddress || emailAddress.indexOf('@') === -1) {
      continue;
    }

    var domain = emailAddress.split('@')[1];
    if (!emailsByDomain[domain]) {
      emailsByDomain[domain] = [];
    }
    emailsByDomain[domain].push({ row: i, email: emailAddress });
  }

  // Process each domain
  for (var domain in emailsByDomain) {
    // Filter out already sent emails
    var unsentEmails = emailsByDomain[domain].filter(emailInfo => !sentEmails[emailInfo.email]);

    // Continue if all emails in the domain have been sent
    if (unsentEmails.length === 0) continue;

    var emailToSend = unsentEmails[Math.floor(Math.random() * unsentEmails.length)]; // Random selection

    var name = data[emailToSend.row][3]; // Name from the selected email row
    var personalizedMessage = message.replace("{name}", name);
    var emailAddress = emailToSend.email;
    var subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    var options = {
      attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    };

    try {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, personalizedMessage, options);
      Logger.log("Emailed " + name + " (" + emailAddress + ")");

      // Set the background color of the row to light green after sending the email
      sheet.getRange(startRow + emailToSend.row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackgroundRGB(200, 255, 200);

      // Update the date in Column F
      var dateCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + emailToSend.row, 6); // Column F is the 6th column
      dateCell.setValue(new Date());

      // Mark this email as sent
      sentEmails[emailAddress] = true;
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log("Failed to send email to " + name + " (" + emailAddress + "): " + e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Input is "Active" tab on GoogleSheets

```
A       B.      C.      D.      E.      F                ... H
COMPANY SALUTE  LAST    FIRST   EMAIL   Emailed on           Message
```

I am picking up `message` and emailing it to `E`

The problem is ... something inserts `\n` making things look great on Mobile devices but cut off on Web.

I tried

1. Putting text in a cell instead of a range
2. forcibly removing all \n all together

Running out of ideas here. Please help

1. **Actual**. All text is in burgundy space
2. **Expected**. Text gracefully
   extends yellow space

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's coming from the name.  Just use the debugger and single step through the script until you find it.

Comment: Where is the `\n` being inserted?

Comment: Are you sure there's an actual `\n` being inserted, rather than the browser doing line wrap?

Comment: Not sure guys! I tried removing all formatting alltogether. It seems that cut off happens around 80 characters or so. I am going zero processing past "get whatever is in that cell and email it as is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it

```
var options = {
  attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],htmlBody: "<pre>" + personalizedMessage + "</pre>" // Wrap the message in <pre> tags
};
```